# >90% of the time is spent on method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, profiling, cprofile

To identify the step that is using most of the computation time, I ran cProfile and got the following result:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.014    0.014  216.025  216.025 func_poolasync.py:2(<module>)
    11241  196.589    0.017  196.589    0.017 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
      982    0.010    0.000  196.532    0.200 threading.py:309(wait)
     1000    0.002    0.000  196.498    0.196 pool.py:565(get)
     1000    0.005    0.000  196.496    0.196 pool.py:557(wait)
515856/3987    0.350    0.000   13.434    0.003 artist.py:230(stale)
```

The step on which most of the time is spent clearly seems to be `method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects`. I have not used threading; rather I've used `pool.apply_async` with several processors, so I'm confused why `thread.lock` is the issue?

I am hoping to have some light shed on why this is the bottleneck? And how to bring down this time?

Here's how the code looks:

```
path='/usr/home/work'
filename='filename'

with open(path+filename+'/'+'result.pickle', 'rb') as f:
     pdata = pickle.load(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()    
    results=[]
    data=list(range(1000))
    print('START')
    start_time = int(round(time.time()))
    result_objects = [pool.apply_async(func, args=(nomb,pdata[0],pdata[1],pdata[2])) for nomb in data]

    results = [r.get() for r in result_objects]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('END', int(round(time.time()))-start_time)
```

**Revision:**

By switching from `pool.apply_async` to `pool.map` I am able to reduce the execution time by ~3 times.

Output:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.113    0.113   70.824   70.824 func.py:2(<module>)
     4329   28.048    0.006   28.048    0.006 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000   28.045    7.011 threading.py:309(wait)
        1    0.000    0.000   28.044   28.044 pool.py:248(map)
        1    0.000    0.000   28.044   28.044 pool.py:565(get)
        1    0.000    0.000   28.044   28.044 pool.py:557(wait)
```

Modification to code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()    
    data=list(range(1000))

    print('START')
    start_time = int(round(time.time()))
    funct = partial(func,pdata[0],pdata[1],pdata[2])
    results = pool.map(funct,data)
    print('END', int(round(time.time()))-start_time)
```

But, it has been found that **some** of the iterations result in nonsensical results. I'm not sure why this is happening, however, it is seen that 
'method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects' is still the rate determining step.

Comment: were you able to understand why this is the bottleneck? I have a very similar problem.

Comment: It might be different for you. For me, the 'func' contained plotting figures requiring the pool to create matplotlib artists each time the 'func' was called. I created the matplotlib artists outside the function and only populated them when the function was called. I refer you to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569306/populating-matplotlib-subplots-through-a-loop-and-a-function, if you too have a similar situation.