# Plot subplots with the results of a nested loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot

I would like to plot 8 subplots for each rescued dog race.

```py
rescued_pop = 8
rescued_dog_race = ["rottweiler", "poodle", "pitbull", "chihuahua", "shihtzu", "whippet", "terrier", "greyhound"]
rescued = float(df.loc[df.breed == rescued_dog_race,"rescued"].to_string(index=False))

for j in range(7):    
    for i in range(1000):
        simulated_dog_race = np.random.choice(["yes", "no"], size = 100, p=[rescued[j]/100,1-(rescued[j]/100)])
        num_rescued = np.sum(simulated_dog_race == "yes")
        null_outcomes.append(num_rescued)
        print(i,rescued[j],null_outcomes)
    print(i,rescued[j],null_outcomes)
```

The dataframe looks like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5u8w.png)

Currently I can generate a bar plot for a define "rescued_dog_race".

```
np.random.seed(1)

rescued_pop = 8
rescued_dog_race = "whippet"
rescued = float(df.loc[df.breed == rescued_dog_race,"rescued"].to_string(index=False))

null_outcomes = []
null_outcomes_pop = []

for i in range(1000):
        simulated_dog_race = np.random.choice(["yes", "no"], size = 100, p=[rescued/100,1-(rescued/100)])
        num_rescued = np.sum(simulated_dog_race == "yes")
        null_outcomes.append(num_rescued)
             
for i in range(1000):
        simulated_pop = np.random.choice(["yes", "no"], size = 100, p=[rescued_pop/100,1-(rescued_pop/100)])
        num_rescued_pop = np.sum(simulated_pop == "yes")
        null_outcomes_pop.append(num_rescued_pop)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJEZK.png)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. What's `rescued`? And what exactly is your question? Are you asking how to get the number of `yes` answers? Are you asking how to plot a barplot of a list containing ints? Could you provide more code of what you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [populating matplotlib subplots through a loop and a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569306/populating-matplotlib-subplots-through-a-loop-and-a-function)

Comment: OP says _"I would like to plot a histogram for each j (so 8 subplots)"_ and their code is _"`for j in range(7):`"_ — oh well, Python does not work like that…

Comment: I can make a barplot with rescued_dog_race = "whippet" for example. But I am wondering if I could avoid changing 8 times the input value in order to get 8 bar plots at once...

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to simplify your solution:

**Remove the for-loop and define the random size directly**
Instead of using a loop until m=1000 with random arrays of size n=100, define the size directly via `size=(m,n)`

```
simulated = np.random.choice(["yes", "no"], size = (1000,100), p=[prop/100,1-(prop/100)])
null_outcomes = list(np.sum(simulated=='yes',axis=1))
```

**Move calculation to a separate function**
and do something with every breed via `df.apply`, e.g.

```
def get_null_outcomes(prop):
    simulated = np.random.choice(["yes", "no"], size = (1000,100), p=[prop/100,1-(prop/100)])
    return list(np.sum(simulated=='yes',axis=1))

df.apply(lambda x: get_null_outcomes(x['rescued']), axis=1)
```

Consequently, you can plot the resulting data in a bar chart, store it in a separate column of your `df`.

### Complete Example (based on your code)

```
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'breed': ['rottweiler', 'poodle', 'pitbull', 'chihuahua', 'shihtzu', 'whippet', 'terrier', 'greyhound'],
    'not_rescued': [85, 86, 87, 90, 93, 94, 96, 97],
    'rescued': [16, 14, 13, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3]
})

def get_null_outcomes(prop):
    simulated = np.random.choice(["yes", "no"], size = (1000,100), p=[prop/100,1-(prop/100)])
    return list(np.sum(simulated=='yes',axis=1))

#pop data
rescued_pop = 8
null_outcomes_pop = get_null_outcomes(rescued_pop)

#plot pop data
plt.hist(null_outcomes_pop, color='orange', stacked=True, alpha=0.2)
plt.axvline(rescued_pop, color='g', label='expected dog rescued')
plt.axvline( np.percentile(null_outcomes_pop, 2.5), color='purple', linestyle='dashed', label='2.5% percentile' )
plt.axvline( np.percentile(null_outcomes_pop, 97.5), color='purple', linestyle='dashed', label='97.5% percentile' )

#dog race data
df['null_outcomes'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_null_outcomes(x['rescued']), axis=1)

#plot dog race data (e.g. for whippet)
plt.hist(df['null_outcomes'][5], histtype='step', fill=False, label=df['breed'][5])
plt.axvline(df['rescued'][5], linestyle='dashed')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

### Some more hints

Plot all at once instead of plotting a bar chart for one race only

```
plt.hist(df['null_outcomes'], histtype='step', fill=False, label=df['breed'])
```

Plot both the histogramm and the vertical line for all with the same color via

```
cm = plt.cm.RdBu_r
for i in range(len(df['breed'])):
    c = color=cm(i/len(df['breed']))
    plt.hist(df['null_outcomes'][i], color=c, histtype='step', fill=False, label=df['breed'][i])
    plt.axvline(df['rescued'][i], color=c, linestyle='dashed')
```

Comment: Thank for the answer ! I see but now  I am realizing that I have trouble following the data structure that I should used .I got the following error: p' must be 1-dimensional.

Comment: how p can be a one dimensional array and actually why ?

Comment: I added a complete example for clarification. In addition, may look into `np.random.normal` instead of calculating a random normal distribution yourself

Comment: I got it ! Thank a lot, merci.

Comment: I have a general question. So in Python it looks like it is better to work with the index of a row  instead of the element contains in the first columns for example ? Is it right ? In my case, I would prefer use something like df[breed = whippet]

Comment: Well, you can use `index` to search for the index first and use the variable then instead of the hard-coded 5 in the example above: `dogIndex = df.index[df.breed == 'whippet'][0]` and then `df['null_outcomes'][dogIndex], histtype='step', fill=False, label=df['breed'][dogIndex]`, etc.

Comment: To increase readability though, may use for instance: `dogData = df.loc[df.breed == 'whippet']` and then `plt.hist( dogData.null_outcomes.item(), histtype='step', fill=False, label=dogData.breed.item() )` etc